# When should I write a symbol in italic type, when upright?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes get confused with scientific notation. Sometimes things are in italic font, sometimes in upright font. I know that it is $\ce{H2O}$, not $H_2O$. But is it $e$ or $\mathrm{e}$? Is it $pK_a$ or $\mathrm{pK_a}$ or something mixed?

Comment: See also http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945

Comment: I would propose [meta-tag:support] and [meta-tag:faq-proposed] for this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In chemistry, the universal scientific convention is:

- Variables and physical constants are written in italic type.
- Chemical elements, operators, units, descriptive subscripts, mathematical constants etc. are written in upright type.

*Example:* $\ce{H}$ stands for hydrogen, $H$ for enthalpy.

> *Examples:* $H$ denotes enthalpy, but $H_\mathrm{m}$ denotes molar enthalpy ($\mathrm{m}$ is a mnemonic label for molar, and
>   is therefore roman). $C_p$ and $C_V$ denote the heat capacity at constant pressure $p$ and volume $V$,
>   respectively; but $C_{p,\mathrm{m}}$ and $C_{V,\mathrm{m}}$ denote the molar heat capacity at constant $p$ and $V$, respectively (note the
>   roman $\mathrm{m}$ but italic $p$ and $V$).
>   
>   [from: IUPAC 2-page summary]

---

Regarding the examples in the question:

- italic $e$ stands for a variable, the elementary charge
- upright $\mathrm{e}$ stands for an electron or Euler's number
- It is $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$, with the $\mathrm{p}$ operator and the $\mathrm{a}$ subscript for 'acid' being upright and $K$ being and italic variable. (`$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$`)

---

References (with many more details and examples):

- [IUPAC: Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Green-Book-PDF-Version-2011.pdf) section 1.6
- [IUPAC: On the use of italic and roman fonts for symbols in scientific text](https://www.iupac.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ICTNS-On-the-use-of-italic-and-roman-fonts-for-symbols-in-scientific-text.pdf) (2-page summary),
- [IUPAP: Symbols, Units, Nomenclature and Fundamental Constants in Physics](http://iupap.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/A4.pdf) section 1.1.2
- [NIST: Typefaces for Symbols in Scientific Manuscripts](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/typefaces.pdf) (2 pages)
- ACS Style Guide, Chapter 11 (in particular sections "Italic Type", "Roman Type", "Subscripts and Superscripts")
- ISO, EN, DIN, ...

---

The convention is not as clear in other fields than chemistry. In physics, for instance, the [APS style](https://journals.aps.org/files/styleguide-pr.pdf) (writing most single-letter operators and abbreviations in italic) contradicts IUPAP and NIST .

Comment: The standardized symbol for molar heat capacity at constant pressure and at constant volume is $C_{\mathrm m,p}$ and $C_{\mathrm m,V}$, respectively (not $C_{p,\mathrm m}$ and $C_{V,\mathrm m}$ – this is an unfortunate nonconformity in the otherwise nice two-page summary).